# Unity C# Calling script via string with varying name

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

My goal is during my combat script, to call a death function from CombatHandler to the script thats attached to the enemy. The problem is that enemy's do not stay the same, thus meaning the script name will have to change!
For example, one enemy will have a script named EnemySalamander, the next will have a script called EnemyGoblin (these controlling the enemy stats, ect)

Here is the Code snippet from combat handler

```
if (healthEnemy < 0) {
    healthEnemy = 0;
    Debug.Log ("You killed a "+nameEnemy+". You have "+ps.health+" health left!");
    //pcc.gameObject.scriptname.death ();
    clearEnemy ();
} else if (ps.health < 0) {
    clearEnemy ();
    ps.health = 0;
    Debug.Log ("You died with the enemys health left at " + healthEnemy);
}
```

I have commented out the part where I need to call the death method on the gameObject's script.
Pcc.gameobject is where I have direct access to the gameObject(Enemy) I am attacking.

Comment: This calls for OOP Principles! Do all of your scripts extend a common base class (e.g. `Enemy`)? If so, `GetComponent<Enemy>()` works!

Comment: Yes! they inherit a class called "EnemyBase", so I can call that class instead?

Comment: public class EnemySalamander : EnemyBase {
 void Start () {
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [`GetComponent()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) does.  The official documentation doesn't make it clear that passing in a class will also find any component that is a subclass of the indicated Type, but it will:

> ## [Getting derived class using base class in GetComponent?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/764376/getting-derived-class-using-base-class-in-getcompo.html)
>
> Yes, this will work as I believe you expect it to.

There isn't a decent chunk of text from the Unity Answers QA to really quote. It goes from that straight into an implementation and results.